# How can I set margin for Components using FlexBox?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I have been setting margins for flexbox by creating empty View components with the flex that I needed, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do this more elegantly. Here is what I've been doing:

```
const MyComponent = () => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text>My real content here</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

See that I just put that first inner view to give the proper margin that I want. Is there an elegant (aka correct) way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with wrapping by wrapping your `flexbox` content inside element and apply margin to this `element` like this html and css:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
}
.row-flex{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
width:100vw
}
.col{
width:calc(100%/3);
 height:200px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.content{
background-color:green;
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-flex">
<div class="col">
<div class="content"></div>
  </div>
<div class="col">
<div class="content"></div></div>
<div class="col">
<div class="content"></div></div>
<div class="col">
<div class="content"></div></div>
<div class="col">
<div class="content"></div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you really need an inner view to set margin. You can give the margin to parent view of Textcomponent.

Can you share screenshot maybe I can guide you better?

```
const MyComponent = () => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 20 }}>
      <Text>My real content here</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: I am not looking to a hardcoded margin, but a responsive/flexible margin, with the same size of my content

Comment: Okay, you can use percentage. For e.g margin: '1%'